# sscanf usage in very specific format

Tags: c

I'm trying to use sscanf with a string that is exactly in the following format:

> integer1 integer2

so that i can store int1 and int2 into an array

I want sscanf to check if only two numbers are entered separated by only ONE space, with no leading or trailing whitespace at all.
Examples of what should and shouldn't work:

Should

```
4 7
```

Shouldn't

```
   4 7
4 7[WHITESPACE] 
4    7
4 7a
```

I've been trying to use it in the following way

```
sscanf(str,"%d %d",&value1,&value2);

if (*STRING CONTAINS INVALID CHARACTERS OR WHITESPACE*){
    exit from parent function }
```

Comment: Simple: don't use sscanf. Use `strtol` and play with the array directly.

Comment: Since all the numeric conversions in `sscanf()` and family skip over leading white space, you have to work every bit as hard as in chux's answer using `sscanf()` — it is really not the appropriate tool.  And careful use of `strtol()` is likely to be a good way to deal with it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Note that `strtol()` and family also skip leading white-space.  Using `strtol()` is the better function primarily due to well defined OF handling - something that detailed by OP yet. `strtol()` has minor `int/long` type concerns.

Comment: @chux: true — I didn't make it clear that `strtol()` also skips leading white space, but that was part of the 'careful use' qualifier, albeit one that should probably have been stated clearly.  I wonder why the input format must be so rigorous.  In general, the [Robustness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) says "be generous in what you accept; be careful in what you generate".  I wonder if that should be applied here.

Comment: Are signs allowed in the data (`-3 +4`)?  All the normal tools will allow signs through; if there should be no signs, then you have another set of validation  to do — and `sscanf()` becomes even less appropriate.  You'd need to check that you have a digit at the start, a digit at the end, only digits and a single space in between, and that the values in the digit strings are convertible safely.  Fiddly!

Comment: Among the many other problems with the `*scanf()` functions, they have undefined behavior on numeric overflow.

Comment: strongly suggest reading in a whole line, then write your own parser to parse that line.  The scanf() family of functions are not the appropriate tools for what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: read the line (note OP implies code is starting with a string so this step is illustrative.)

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF_or_Error();
// strip potential \n
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
```

---

> check if only two numbers are entered separated by only ONE space, with no leading or trailing whitespace at all

Step 2: Scan per format.  `"%d"` allows for leading whitespace - so code needs to see what is before the numeric text.  Use `"%n"` to store the scan offset for later  whitespace detection.  `%*1[ ]` to scan (not save) 1 and exactly 1 space.

```
int i[2];
int sep[3];
int cnt = sscanf(buf, "%n%d%*1[ ]%n%d%n", &sep[0], &i[0], &sep[1], &i[1], &sep[2]);

// 2 int            leading space?        leading space?        \0 ?
if (cnt != 2 || isspace(buf[sep[0]]) || isspace(buf[sep[1]]) || buf[sep[2]]) {
  Handle_Bad_Input();
} else {
  Success();
}
```

---

Simplification idea per [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718718/sscanf-usage-in-very-specific-format/45718850?noredirect=1#comment78398389_45718850)

```
int i[2];
int sep[2];
int cnt = sscanf(buf, "%d%*1[ ]%n%d%n", &i[0], &sep[0], &i[1], &sep[1]);

// 2 int        leading space?     leading space?          \0 ?
if (cnt != 2 || isspace(buf[0]) || isspace(buf[sep[0]]) || buf[sep[1]]) {
```

---

Note: pedantic code would cast the `char` with `(unsigned char)` to handle negative `char` as `is...()` functions are defined for the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.

```
isspace(buf[...]) --> isspace((unsigned char) buf[...])
```

### ---

A more robust approach would call a helper function to assess the integer - which can be crafted per code's needs.  Using `strtol()` is a good starting point for define-ness and overflow detection.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Return error status
bool scan_int(const char **input, int *dest) {
  errno = 0;
  const char *s = *input;

  if (isspace((unsigned char) *s) {
    // reject leading space
    return true;
  }

  char *endptr;
  long num = strtol(s, &endptr, 10);
  if (s == endptr) {
    // no conversion
    return true;
  }
  *input = (const char *) endptr;
  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    // Overflow
    return true;
  }
#if LONG_MAX > INT_MAX  || LONG_MIN < INT_MIN
  if (num > INT_MAX || num < INT_MIN) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    // Overflow
    return true;
  }
#endif
  *dest = (int) num;
  return false;
}

// Return error status - On success, return false
bool sz_int_space_int(const char *input, int *dest) {
  return scan_int(&input, &dest[0]) || *input++ != ' '
      || scan_int(&input, &dest[1]) || *input;
}
```

Comment: Excellent demonstration of both the power of `sscanf()` et al and also of the intricacy of getting it all right when you need to be stringent.

Comment: Silly Q time: when will the first `%n` in your format string return a value that isn't 0?  Do you want a space before it?  Or can you simply test `isspace(buf[0])`?

Comment: Yes, using `isspace(buf[0])` or the pedatic `isspace((unsigned char) buf[0])` would simplify code - good eye.  A singular advantage to `"%n%d"` is that it is symmetric for the 2 `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you only deal with positive integers without leading signs, here is a simpler solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int validate_string(const char *buf, int *int1, int *int2) {
    size_t len1, len2;
    /* return non 0 if and only if line has the correct format
       and int1 and int2 contain the converted numbers */
    return (len1 = strspn(buf, "0123456789")) > 0
    &&     buf[len1] == ' '
    &&     (len2 = strspn(buf + len1 + 1, "0123456789")) > 0
    &&     buf[len1 + len2 + 1] == '\0'
    &&     sscanf(buf, "%d%d", int1, int2) == 2);
}
```

Note however that this solution does not adequately test for potential overflow in the numeric conversions.

Here is an alternative with `strtol()`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parse_int(int *dest, const char *buf, char **pp)
int validate_string(const char *buf, int *int1, int *int2) {
    char *p1, *p2;
    return !isspace((unsigned char)*buf)
    &&     ((*int1 = strtol(buf, &p1, 10)), p1 > buf)
    &&     *p1++ == ' '
    &&     !isspace((unsigned char)*p1)
    &&     ((*int2 = strtol(p1, &p2, 10)), p2 > p1)
    &&     *p2 == '\0');
}
```

Modified to avoid implementation defined behavior commmented by chux:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parse_int(int *dest, const char *buf, char **pp) {
    long val;
    if (isspace((unsigned char)*buf)
        return 0;
    val = strtol(buf, pp, 10);
    if (*pp <= buf)
        return 0;
    if (val < INT_MIN) {
        val = INT_MIN;
        errno = ERANGE;
    } else
    if (val > INT_MAX) {
        val = INT_MAX;
        errno = ERANGE;
    }
    *dest = (int)val;
    return 1;
}

int validate_string(const char *buf, int *int1, int *int2) {
    char *p1, *p2;
    return parse_int(int1, buf, &p1)
    &&     *p1++ == ' '
    &&     parse_int(int2, p1, &p2)
    &&     *p2 == '\0');
}
```

Here is one with just a single `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int validate_string(const char *buf, int *int1, int *int2) {
    int p1, p2, p3;
    char c;
    return sscanf(buf, " %n%d%1*[ ]%n %n%d%c", &p1, int1, &p2, &p3, int2, &c) == 2
        && p1 == 0 && p2 == p3;
}
```

Comment: 1st one is good and novel.  2nd one has minor issue (implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised)  of `some_int = some_long`.

Comment: @chux: yes, a minor issue but correct. To avoid it, a simple implementation of `strtoi()` as a wrapper on `strtol()` with some extra tests would do the job. How do you like the third one?

Comment: 3rd one looks fully functionally correct to me too with its "sscanf append %c, but fail to read  into it" code.